# Is it possible to execute MySQLdb executemany function using a mapping(dictionary)

Tags: python, mysql-python

I know that we can use executemany this way:

```
sql = "insert into a(c1,c2,c3) values(%s,%s,%s)"
seq_of_parameters = [('a','b','c'),('a','b','c')]
cu.executemany(sql,seq_of_parameters)
```

I wonder why this doesn't work:

```
sql = "insert into a(c1,c2,c3) values(%(c1)s,%(c2)s,%(c3)s)"
seq_of_parameters = [{'c1':'a','c2':'b','c3':'c'},{'c1':'a','c2':'b','c3':'c'}]
cu.executemany(sql,seq_of_parameters)
```

From PEP249 Python Database API Specification v2.0

> .executemany(operation,seq_of_parameters)
>
> Prepare a database operation (query or command) and then
>               execute it against all parameter **sequences or mappings**
>               found in the sequence seq_of_parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it supports mapping via another way, not using `%(c1)s`, but using

```
params = [ ('c1', 1), ('c2', 2) ]
executemany("insert into a(c1, c2) values (?, ?)", params)
```

you may try this :

```
from string import Template
Template('$c1, $c3, $c3').safe_substitute({'c1':1, 'c2':2, 'c3':3})
```

executemany may not implement using Template, but simply using string.format, as it does not make any assumption on your parameters name.

Comment: maybe MySQLdb just doesn't support it.use sequence of tuple is just fine